# Decrypt PGP string in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, gnupg, pgp

I've looked for an answer four about an hour now and can't find anything.

This would usually be easy, but:

We're not able to write to files or call an external file.

We cannot use the BouncyCastle API.

Most of the libraries I'm finding require calling pgp.exe(or similar), which is out of the question.

We have the public/private keys and are being passed an encrypted string.

Is there an easy way to decrypt this in C#/.NET4?

Comment: Why not use [portable pgp](http://ppgp.sourceforge.net/) and have to program encryption/decryption when the PGP source code is for review only?

Comment: Did you check our SecureBlackbox ? It doesn't use pgp.exe and doesn't require files to be on the disk.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. We came up with a solution, if this question is reopened, I will post it as an answer.